# Unable to telnet web server on a port that's listening

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

I'm implementing sockets on my website and bound a socket to the IP address of the website but when I telnet the website on that port, it doesn't connect. The sockets are being created and the website is listening for incoming connections, there's no errors but the error is shown when trying to telnet the website. If i change the code to listen on `127.0.0.1`, it works with no problems.

The website is listening on port `6662` which is an unofficial IRC port. What is not happening?

I do the following to telnet the website.

```
telnet www.nameofwebsite.com 6662
telnet ipofwebsite 6662
```

it tries connecting then fails with an error saying: Could not open connection to the host, on port 6662: Connect failed

The end script is a small and simple.

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_NOTICE);

    $address = "ipofwebsite";    // if i change this to 127.0.0.1 and telnet localhost 6662, it works.
    $port = 6662;

    # root socket
    $root = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

    # reuse socket
    if( socket_set_option($root, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) == false )
    {
        echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    }

    # bind socket
    if( socket_bind($root, $address, $port) === false )
    {
        echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    }

    # listen on the socket
    if( socket_listen($root) === false )
    {
        echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    }

    # accept a connection
    if( ( $client = socket_accept($root) ) === false )
    {
        echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    }
    echo "Connection accepted<br />";

    socket_close($root);

?>
```

It keeps listening but doesn't accept any telnet connection.

Comment: kaspersky installed and updated..could it be? but it allows to connect to localhost

Comment: Maybe, your server blocks the port 6662

Comment: where do you run this script? browser or cli? I think the socket is only open until the first timeout then the script will end and the socket is closed. you may need a `while(true){}` loop to keep it open there's a great example of a php listening server here http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php#Hcom44501

Comment: @andrew, i'd like to run it on the browser.

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen, i've tried several different ports

Answer (score 0):

If your server is a Windows server please try this:`https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html.`

And if your system is Linux please try run command as below:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport your_port_number -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Or may be run command as below  if it is CentOS 7

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=your_port_number /tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```